# How to collect a list of all contact points handled by the unity physics engine that frame

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I need a 3D equivalent to `Collider2D.GetContacts` for ground deteciton in my platformer, but I can't see how to do this neatly, in theory the physics engine should be keeping track of these points anyway, so this should be possible without any extra processing, but I can't figure out how. A 3D equivalent to this function simply doesn't seem to exist, so what is the best alternative?

Comment: The only route I can think of is to register all the reported Collisions for a given Collider, and those Collisions with have a `GetContacts()` you can call.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCastAll.html or https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html or https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBox.html... etc in the class https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.html

Comment: Absinthe I don't want to use any of those because that means unity is doing the same calculations twice, I want to use the ouput of the collider

Comment: Bart can you show me how that would work